# PHP file isn't executing all 3 queries

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that has POST variables coming from an iOS application.

What I'd like to happen is for it to check if my POST variables are empty. If not, I want it to execute the query I've written. What I'm finding is that it only executes that last query in the list of 3 that I have. I've even switched the order of the 3 and it seems to still only execute the last one even though all 3 are TRUE.

```
$item = $_POST['item'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$salePrice = $_POST['salePrice'];
$newItemUpdate = $_POST['newItemUpdate'];
if(isset($item))
{
    $query = "UPDATE Price_List Set Item = ('".$newItemUpdate."') WHERE Item = ('".$item."')";
}
if(isset($salePrice))
{
    $query = "UPDATE Price_List Set SalePrice = ('".$salePrice."') WHERE Item = ('".$item."')";
}
if(isset($price))
{
    $query = "UPDATE Price_List Set Price = ('".$price."') WHERE Item = ('".$item."')";
}
```

Comment: change $query variable it overriding query or execute inside if statement

Comment: You should execute each query inside the respective statement. Also you are wide open to SQL injection attacks. I hope you can see that

Comment: where you have `execute` the query

Answer (score 1):

You are using $query variable for all three queries, causing overwriting top two variables.
please change your variable names or execute the query at every condition.

Answer (score 0):

Either execute each `query` inside the if condition before moving on to the next `query` or use different variable names for each query if you want to execute them later. Shown below:

```
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $salePrice = $_POST['salePrice'];
    $newItemUpdate = $_POST['newItemUpdate'];
    if(isset($item))
     {
       $query1 = "UPDATE Price_List Set Item = ('".$newItemUpdate."') WHERE Item = 
       ('".$item."')";
     }
   if(isset($salePrice))
    {
      $query2 = "UPDATE Price_List Set SalePrice = ('".$salePrice."') WHERE Item = 
      ('".$item."')";
    }
  if(isset($price))
   {
     $query3 = "UPDATE Price_List Set Price = ('".$price."') WHERE Item = 
     ('".$item."')";
   }
```

Comment: Now it's only executing the first one haha.

Comment: How exactly are you executing the query? Mind sharing the code here?

Comment: $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query1);
 $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query2);
 $result3 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query3);
    
    echo $result1;
 echo $result2;
 echo $result3;

Comment: And how do you know it is executing the first one only? Did you check the database or relying on `mysqli_query()` return values?
Moreover, your $_POST parameters could be blank too because `isset()` does not check for blank values.

Comment: Yes, I am checking against the database. I can see the first field update but it's not updating the other two.

Comment: That's because in the first query, you update the `Item` field to `$newItemUpdate` but then in the next queries, you are updating the values against `$item`, which actually has been over-written in DB by your first query. Therefore, no matches occur. Use `$newItemUpdate` instead of `$item` in `$query2` and `$query3`.

Answer (score 0):

Because You have used same name for `query` variable thats why last `query` variable overwrite above both query variable and its only execute last query.

so need to change variable name and execute three time or else execute inside if condition after `query`

```
$item = $_POST['item'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$salePrice = $_POST['salePrice'];
$newItemUpdate = $_POST['newItemUpdate'];
if(isset($item))
{
    $query = "UPDATE Price_List Set Item = ('".$newItemUpdate."') WHERE Item = ('".$item."')";
    //query execute here
}
if(isset($salePrice))
{
    $query = "UPDATE Price_List Set SalePrice = ('".$salePrice."') WHERE Item = ('".$item."')";
   //query execute here
}
if(isset($price))
{
    $query = "UPDATE Price_List Set Price = ('".$price."') WHERE Item = ('".$item."')";
    //query execute here
}

//OR execute with different name 
//execute query1
//execute query2
//execute query3
```